# Ruby Single versus Double Quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there some sort of Ruby `to_s` method that changes a variable to a single-quoted string instead of double quotes?

Say I have

```
date = Time.now
date.to_s
```

and I want the output to be '2012-08-01 22:00:15'. How do I go about doing this? Or is there a method to convert "" strings to '' strings?

Thanks!

**EDIT - More Detail**

I'm using Rails to display some data in a database. I've created the `@instanceVar` as an array of arrays from my Controller/Model.

```
<% outer = [] %>
<% inner = [] %>

<% @instanceVar.each do |events| %>
  <% events.each do |event| %>
    <% inner << [event.date, event.total] %>
  <% end %>
  <% outer << inner %>
<% end %>
```

I need `event.date` to be a single quoted string.

```
    <% inner << ['event.date', event.total] %>
```

just literally adds the words `event.date` to the array, and

```
    <% inner << ["#{event.date}", event.total] %>
```

puts the date in double quotes.

**EDIT2**

```
<script>
  $.jqplot('trendingEvents', <%= outer %>,
  {
    #options go here
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are strings in ruby. They are all equal. The only difference is how you declare them (single quotes, double quotes, here-docs and maybe something else). Once you've got a string value in a variable, it doesn't matter how it was declared.

```
s1 = 'single quoted'
s1 # => "single quoted"
```

So, if your strings don't leave the rubyland (that is, you don't render them as javascript or whatever), you shouldn't worry about the quotes.

#### Response to edit 2

It seems that you have to build your json object in a more manual manner, rather than relying on default behaviour of `Array#to_s`

To emit ruby string as javascript single-quoted string literal you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var s = '<%= ruby_string %>';
</script>
```

`<%= %>` construct will render passed string without quotes. You supply the quotes yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but I'm using jqPlot to create a line graph with a date x-axis. The date parameter needs to be a string for the dateAxisRenderer to function. If I insert something double quoted, jqPlot escapes the quotes into `&QUOT;`. Using `html_safe` does nothing.

Comment: So, where's the part where you render those vars as javascript?

Comment: So there's no way of doing this outside the script? I'm going to have to run my loop inside, okay, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Double-quotes as a string constructor allow you to interpolate variables.  Single quotes are for literals.  As mentioned, a string is a string once instantiated, displaying quotes is better left to the caller.

Comment: See my comment to Sergio for details as to why this matters.